# isConsecutive with PriorityQueue. How to +1 to Objects when comparing?

Tags: java, object

So here is the original problem Im working on from practice it.  Write a method called isConsecutive that accepts a PriorityQueue of integers as a parameter and returns true if the queue contains a sequence of consecutive integers starting from the front of the queue.  So far I have the following but the main problem I have is how to "add 1" to objects to see if they are consecutive.

>

```
 public static boolean isConsecutive(PriorityQueue o){
>           if(o.isEmpty()){
>               return true;
>           }
>           while(!(o.isEmpty())){
>            
>               if(o.poll() ==o.peek()){
>                   return true;
>               }
>           }
>           return false;   
>       }
```

Comment: if you want to look at the original problem from practice it its right here --> [link](http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem.jsp?category=Building+Java+Programs%2C+3rd+edition%2FBJP3+Chapter+18&problem=bjp3-18-e10-isConsecutive)

Answer (score 2):

Your function should take a `PriorityQueue<Integer>` object rather than just a plain `PriorityQueue`. Then `o.poll()` `o.peek()` will return `Integer`s rather than plain `Object`s.

Once you have `Integer`s to work with, you can simply use the regular `+` operator.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Cant believe simple mistakes can go a long way.